# Acol Bridge card game

Tags: bridge, scoring

I am playing game in 4 hearts and get four.  The opponents revoke on the 12th trick. If they had not revoked they would of taken us down one trick.
Do we get our four hearts? 
I know a revoke does not get a penalty with the last two tricks of a hand being played.

Comment: No *penalty*, but the revoke is still *corrected.*. See the answer by Fabian velow.

Answer (score 2):

From the ACBL Rules:

> Law 62.D is first applied:
>
> 1. On the 12th trick, a revoke, even if established, must be corrected if discovered before all four hands have been returned to the board.

In Switzerland we have the same ruling for a trick 12 Revoke.

So the revoke will be fully corrected without penalty and the hand is one down.

Comment: I think that's actually from the World Bridge Federation Laws, approved by the ACBL, the European Bridge Federation and - most important since OP specifed 'Acol Bridge' - the EBU.